# Trying to make alienrain in python using the opengl function glMapBufferRange

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, glsl, glut

Just 4 little lines causing a problem with the alien rain program that I ported from the OpenGL Superbible.  It seems I am having issues trying to write to memory after using the function **glMapBufferRange**

Update: Excellent code by Rabbid76 has solved the problem and provided valuable insight of explanation. Thank You.

Required files: [ktxloader.py](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt05/shared/ktxloader.py) , [aliens.ktx](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt05/aliens.ktx)

Source code of alienrain.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import time

sys.path.append("./shared")

#from sbmloader import SBMObject    # location of sbm file format loader
from ktxloader import KTXObject    # location of ktx file format loader

#from sbmath import m3dDegToRad, m3dRadToDeg, m3dTranslateMatrix44, m3dRotationMatrix44, m3dMultiply, m3dOrtho, m3dPerspective, rotation_matrix, translate, m3dScaleMatrix44

fullscreen = True

import numpy.matlib
import numpy as np
import math 

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()

identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]

render_prog = GLuint(0)
render_vao = GLuint(0)

tex_alien_array = GLuint(0)
rain_buffer = GLuint(0)

droplet_x_offset = []
droplet_rot_speed = []
droplet_fall_speed = []


seed = 0x13371337
import random
import ctypes
random.seed (0x13371337)
def random_float():
    # global seed
    # res=0.0
    # tmp=0

    # seed *= 16807;

    # tmp = seed ^ (seed >> 4) ^ (seed << 15);

    # res = (tmp >> 9) | 0x3F800000;

    # return (res - 1.0);
    return (random.random() - 1.0)

class Scene:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        global render_prog
        global render_vao
        global tex_alien_array
        global rain_buffer

        global droplet_x_offset, droplet_rot_speed, droplet_fall_speed

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        vs = GLuint(0)
        fs = GLuint(0)

        vs_source = '''
#version 410 core

layout (location = 0) in int alien_index;

out VS_OUT
{
    flat int alien;
    vec2 tc;
} vs_out;

struct droplet_t
{
    float x_offset;
    float y_offset;
    float orientation;
    float unused;
};

layout (std140) uniform droplets
{
    droplet_t droplet[256];
};

void main(void)
{
    const vec2[4] position = vec2[4](vec2(-0.5, -0.5),
                                     vec2( 0.5, -0.5),
                                     vec2(-0.5,  0.5),
                                     vec2( 0.5,  0.5));
    vs_out.tc = position[gl_VertexID].xy + vec2(0.5);
    float co = cos(droplet[alien_index].orientation);
    float so = sin(droplet[alien_index].orientation);
    mat2 rot = mat2(vec2(co, so),
                    vec2(-so, co));
    vec2 pos = 0.25 * rot * position[gl_VertexID];
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x + droplet[alien_index].x_offset,
                       pos.y + droplet[alien_index].y_offset,
                       0.5, 1.0);
    vs_out.alien = alien_index % 64;
}

'''

        fs_source = '''
#version 410 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

in VS_OUT
{
    flat int alien;
    vec2 tc;
} fs_in;

uniform sampler2DArray tex_aliens;

void main(void)
{
    color = texture(tex_aliens, vec3(fs_in.tc, float(fs_in.alien)));
}

'''

        vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(vs, vs_source)
        glCompileShader(vs)

        glGetShaderInfoLog(vs)

        fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(fs, fs_source)
        glCompileShader(fs)

        glGetShaderInfoLog(vs)

        render_prog = glCreateProgram()
        glAttachShader(render_prog, vs)
        glAttachShader(render_prog, fs)
        glLinkProgram(render_prog)

        glDeleteShader(vs)
        glDeleteShader(fs)

        glGetProgramInfoLog(render_prog)

        glGenVertexArrays(1, render_vao)
        glBindVertexArray(render_vao)

        ktxobj = KTXObject()

        tex_alien_array = ktxobj.ktx_load("aliens.ktx")

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, tex_alien_array)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)

        glGenBuffers(1, rain_buffer)
        glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, rain_buffer)


        glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 256*4*4, None, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)


        for i in range(0, 256):
            droplet_x_offset.append(random_float() * 2.0 - 1.0)
            droplet_rot_speed.append( (random_float() + 0.5) * (-3.0 if (i & 1) else 3.0)  )
            droplet_fall_speed.append ( random_float() + 0.2 )

        glBindVertexArray(render_vao);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    def display(self):
        global rain_buffer

        green = [ 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0 ]
        currentTime = time.time()
        t = currentTime
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green)

        glUseProgram(render_prog);

        glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, rain_buffer);
        droplet = glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 256*4*4, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)
        float_array = ((ctypes.c_float * 4) * 256).from_address(droplet) 



        for i in range(0, 256):
            float_array[i][0] =  droplet_x_offset[i] + 2
            float_array[i][1] =  2.0-math.fmod((t + float(i)) * droplet_fall_speed[i], 4.31 ) * random_float()
            float_array[i][2] =  droplet_rot_speed[i] * t * random_float() * math.pi
            float_array[i][3] = 0.0

        glUnmapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER);

        for alien_index in range(0, 256):
            glVertexAttribI1i(0, alien_index);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);


        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen
        global many_cubes

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle

            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(512, 512)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True

        print('done')

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):

        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/60.0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)

    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)

    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Alien Rain')
    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))

    fullscreen = False
    many_cubes = False
    #glutFullScreen()

    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)

    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)

    scene.init()

    glutMainLoop()
```

Current output is:
Update: very similar to expected output. Except it very fast and the rotations of each alien are not as smooth as the expected output.  If anyone wants to tinker with the values to get it, please do.  Otherwise this question is answered.

The output should be:
[image]

Here's the [alienrain.cpp](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp) that was used to create alienrain.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the 2nd parameter of [`glBufferData`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310310/python-ctypes-how-to-modify-an-existing-char-array) is the buffer data in bytes.

Since the glsl data structure is

```c
struct droplet_t
{
    float x_offset;
    float y_offset;
    float orientation;
    float unused;
};

layout (std140) uniform droplets
{
    droplet_t droplet[256];
};
```

the buffer size is 4*4*256, because the size of a `float` is 4, t he structure has 4 elements of type `flaot` and the array has 256 elements

```py
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 256*4*4, None, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
```

The instruction

```py
droplet = glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 256*4*4, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)
```

returns a pointer to a allocated memory region with the proper size. You've to fill this memory with data.
The easiest solution is to use the (in python built-in) library [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes), which has the handy function [`.from_address()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#data-types):

> This method returns a ctypes type instance using the memory specified by address.

so the instruction

```py
float_array = ((ctypes.c_float * 4) * 256).from_address(droplet)
```

"wraps" a 2 dimensional array to the memory addressed by `droplet`, with 256 elements and each element has 4 elements of type `float`.

The values can be set to the array, by a simple assignment statement. e.g.:

```py
import random
import math
import ctypes
```

```py
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, rain_buffer);
droplet = glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 256*4*4, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)
float_array = ((ctypes.c_float * 4) * 256).from_address(droplet) 
for i in range(0, 256):
    float_array[i][0] = random.random() * 2 -1
    float_array[i][1] = random.random() * 2 -1
    float_array[i][2] = random.random() * math.pi * 2
    float_array[i][3] = 0.0
```

Comment: Yes, very, very nice.  I thought as much, was trying to set a numpy array from address, but that would be unnecessary shown by the amazing code you have provided.  I will update the source code in a bit.  Thank you very much!!!!!!