# asteroids program using indirect draws, glMultiDrawArraysIndirect not rendering and drawing blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, glut, opengl-3

I'm porting a program to learn about indirect draws from Superbible OpenGL 7th ed.  This program is supposed to render almost 1 billion vertices per second and does not get a bottleneck from the rate of submitting draw commands due to using a modern opengl technique of **`glMultiDrawArraysIndirect`**  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank You.

this is the expected output:

[image: expected output of astroids program]

Update:  I'm very grateful for the wonderful help from the Rabbid76 answer.  The code is so good and the insight as to why is refreshing and amazing.  Thank you so much!  The program is displaying the asteroid field as intended!

It does appear that the program runs faster with the indirect draws.

I agree don't seem to use enum as a class right in python.  Plus its probably better not to.

dependency files: [asteroids_support.zip](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt07/asteroids_support.zip) there's an updated sbmloader in the zip

source code of asteroids.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import time
import ctypes

fullscreen = True

sys.path.append("./shared")

from sbmloader import SBMObject    # location of sbm file format loader

from sbmath import m3dDegToRad, m3dRadToDeg, m3dTranslateMatrix44, m3dRotationMatrix44, m3dMultiply, m3dOrtho, m3dPerspective, rotation_matrix, translate, m3dScaleMatrix44, \
    scale, m3dLookAt, normalize

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()

from array import array
from enum import Enum

import numpy as np 
from math import cos, sin 
identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]


render_program = GLuint(0)

myobject = SBMObject()

indirect_draw_buffer = GLuint(0)
draw_index_buffer = GLuint(0)

class uniforms():
    time = GLint(0)
    view_matrix  = GLint(0)
    proj_matrix = GLint(0)
    viewproj_matrix  = GLint(0)

uniform = uniforms()


mode = 1
MODE_MULTIDRAW = 1
MODE_SEPARATE_DRAWS = 2


paused = False
vsync = False

NUM_DRAWS           = 50000


class DrawArraysIndirectCommand:
    count = GLuint(0)
    primCount = GLuint(0)
    first = GLuint(0)
    baseInstance = GLuint(0)




def shader_load(filename, shader_type):

    result = GLuint(0)

    with open ( filename, "rb") as data:

        result = glCreateShader(shader_type)

        glShaderSource(result, data.read() )

    glCompileShader(result)

    return result


def link_from_shaders(shaders, shader_count, delete_shaders, check_errors=False):

    program = GLuint(0)

    program = glCreateProgram()

    for i in range(0, shader_count):
        glAttachShader(program, shaders[i]);

    glLinkProgram(program);

    if (delete_shaders):

        for i in range(0, shader_count):
            glDeleteShader(shaders[i]);

    return program



def load_shaders():

    global render_program
    global uniform

    shaders = [GLuint(0), GLuint(0)]

    shaders[0] = shader_load("render.vs.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    shaders[1] = shader_load("render.fs.glsl", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    if (render_program):
        glDeleteProgram(render_program)

    render_program = link_from_shaders(shaders, 2, True)

    uniform.time            = glGetUniformLocation(render_program, "time")
    uniform.view_matrix     = glGetUniformLocation(render_program, "view_matrix")
    uniform.proj_matrix     = glGetUniformLocation(render_program, "proj_matrix")
    uniform.viewproj_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(render_program, "viewproj_matrix")




class Scene:

    def __init__(self, width, height):

        global myobject
        global indirect_draw_buffer
        global draw_index_buffer

        i=0

        load_shaders()



        myobject.load("asteroids.sbm")

        sizeOfDrawIndCmd = ctypes.sizeof(GLuint*4)

        glGenBuffers(1, indirect_draw_buffer)
        glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, indirect_draw_buffer)
        glBufferData(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER,
                        NUM_DRAWS * sizeOfDrawIndCmd,
                        None,
                        GL_STATIC_DRAW)


        cmd_memory = glMapBufferRange(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER,
                                0,
                                NUM_DRAWS * sizeOfDrawIndCmd,
                                GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)


        cmd_buffer = ((GLuint * 4) * NUM_DRAWS).from_address(cmd_memory) 

        for i in range(0, NUM_DRAWS):
            first, count = myobject.get_sub_object_info(i % myobject.get_sub_object_count())
            cmd_buffer[i][0] = count
            cmd_buffer[i][1] = 1
            cmd_buffer[i][2] = first
            cmd_buffer[i][3] = i

        glUnmapBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER)

        glBindVertexArray(myobject.get_vao())

        glGenBuffers(1, draw_index_buffer)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, draw_index_buffer)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                        NUM_DRAWS * ctypes.sizeof(GLuint),
                        None,
                        GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        draw_index = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                                        0,
                                        NUM_DRAWS * ctypes.sizeof(GLuint),
                                        GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT |
                                        GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)


        int_array = (GLuint * NUM_DRAWS).from_address(draw_index) 

        for i in range(0, NUM_DRAWS):
            int_array[i] = i

        glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)

        glVertexAttribIPointer(10, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, None)
        glVertexAttribDivisor(10, 1)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(10)

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)

        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)




    def display(self):

        global myobject

        currentTime = time.time()

        j=0
        one = 1.0;
        black = [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]


        last_time = 0.0;
        total_time = 0.0;

        if (paused == False):
            total_time += (currentTime - last_time)
        last_time = currentTime

        t = float(total_time)
        i = int(total_time * 3.0)

        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black)
        glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, one)

        view_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        view_matrix = m3dLookAt([100.0 * cos(t * 0.023), 100.0 * cos(t * 0.023), 300.0 * sin(t * 0.037) - 600.0],
                                [0.0, 0.0, 260.0], 
                                normalize([0.1 - cos(t * 0.1) * 0.3, 1.0, 0.0]))

        proj_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(m3dDegToRad(50.0), float(self.width) / float(self.height), 1.0, 2000.0)

        glUseProgram(render_program)

        glUniform1f(uniform.time, t)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform.view_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, view_matrix)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform.proj_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform.viewproj_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, m3dMultiply(proj_matrix , view_matrix))

        glBindVertexArray(myobject.get_vao());


        if (mode == MODE_MULTIDRAW):

            glMultiDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, None, NUM_DRAWS, 0);

        elif (mode == MODE_SEPARATE_DRAWS):

            for j in range(0, NUM_DRAWS):

                first, count = myobject.get_sub_object_info(j % myobject.get_sub_object_count())
                glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance(GL_TRIANGLES,
                                                  first,
                                                  count,
                                                  1, j)

        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen
        global paused
        global mode
        global vsync

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle

            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(512, 512)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True

        elif key == b'p' or key == b'P': #fullscreen toggle
            paused = not paused   # a toggle technique

        elif key == b'v' or key == b'V': #fullscreen toggle
            vsync = not vsync  # a toggle technique
            #setVsync(vsync)


        elif key == b'd' or key == b'D': #fullscreen toggle

                mode += 1
                if (mode  > 2):
                    mode = 1


        print('done')

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):

        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/60.0)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    glutInit()


    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)

    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)

    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Asteroids')
    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))

    fullscreen = False
    many_cubes = False
    #glutFullScreen()

    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)

    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)

    scene.init()

    glutMainLoop()
```

source of ported program:  [multidrawindirect.cpp](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/multidrawindirect/multidrawindirect.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to python functions and methods are not in-out paramters, they are inputs only. But you can return a tuple from a function. Change the method `.get_sub_object_info()` in the class `SBMObject`:

```py
class SBMObject:

    def get_sub_object_info(self, index):
       if (index >= len(sub_object)):
           return 0, 0
       return sub_object[index].first, sub_object[index].count
```

And call it like this:

```py
first, count = myobject.get_sub_object_info(j % myobject.get_sub_object_count())
```

If you want to create a 16 byte structure like the following C++ structure

> ```cpp
> typedef  struct {
>    uint  count;
>    uint  instanceCount;
>    uint  first;
>    uint  baseInstance;
> } DrawArraysIndirectCommand;
> ```

then you can't do it by a python class like this

> ```py
> class DrawArraysIndirectCommand:
>    count = GLuint(0)
>    primCount = GLuint(0)
>    first = GLuint(0)
>    baseInstance = GLuint(0)
> ```

````
This is something completely different in the internal structure and memory layout.  
Further note, that [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) is not the same as [`ctypes.sizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). You can vereify this with ease by:

```py
print(sys.getsizeof(GLuint))
print(ctypes.sizeof(GLuint))
````

A 16 byte element for a "DrawArraysIndirectCommand" can be generated by `GLuint*4` and the size of is:

```py
sizeOfDrawIndCmd = ctypes.sizeof(GLuint*4)
```

[`glMapBufferRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml) returns a pointer to a allocated memory region, "wrap" a 2 dimensional array toby using the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) function [`.from_address()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#data-types).
See [Trying to make alienrain in python using the opengl function glMapBufferRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768267/trying-to-make-alienrain-in-python-using-the-opengl-function-glmapbufferrange).

```py
sizeOfDrawIndCmd = ctypes.sizeof(GLuint*4)

glGenBuffers(1, indirect_draw_buffer)
glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, indirect_draw_buffer)
glBufferData(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER,
                NUM_DRAWS * sizeOfDrawIndCmd,
                None,
                GL_STATIC_DRAW)


cmd_memory = glMapBufferRange(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER,
                        0,
                        NUM_DRAWS * sizeOfDrawIndCmd,
                        GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)


cmd_buffer = ((GLuint * 4) * NUM_DRAWS).from_address(cmd_memory) 

for i in range(0, NUM_DRAWS):
    first, count = myobject.get_sub_object_info(i % myobject.get_sub_object_count())
    cmd_buffer[i][0] = count
    cmd_buffer[i][1] = 1
    cmd_buffer[i][2] = first
    cmd_buffer[i][3] = i

glUnmapBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER)
```

The attributes have an integral data type (`GL_UNSIGNED_INT`). You've to create a buffer with the proper format. The type has to be `GLuint` (or `ctypes.c_uint`) rather than `ctypes.c_float`:

<s>`int_array = ((ctypes.c_float ) * NUM_DRAWS).from_address(draw_index)`</s>
`int_array = (GLuint * NUM_DRAWS).from_address(draw_index)`

And use `ctypes.sizeof(GLuint)` rather than `sys.getsizeof(GLuint)`:

```py
glGenBuffers(1, draw_index_buffer)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, draw_index_buffer)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                NUM_DRAWS * ctypes.sizeof(GLuint),
                None,
                GL_STATIC_DRAW)

draw_index = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                                0,
                                NUM_DRAWS * ctypes.sizeof(GLuint),
                                GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT |
                                GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)


int_array = (GLuint * NUM_DRAWS).from_address(draw_index) 

for i in range(0, NUM_DRAWS):
    int_array[i] = i

glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Amazing code, thank you so much!!!  Yes, I see where I went wrong, and I will use ctypes.sizeof() from now on.  Very nice fix on the SBMObject.  Thank You.  I will update the source code right away.